# Windows API, VB.Net GetModuleFileNameEx, Entry Point Not Found

Tags: c++, vb.net, winapi

I'm trying to run the code below:

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Declare Function GetModuleFileNameEx Lib "PSAPI.DLL" (ByVal hProcess As Integer, ByVal hModule As Integer, ByRef lpFilename As String, ByVal nSize As Integer) As Integer
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim _intLen As Integer
        Dim lpFilename As String
        Dim nSize As Integer
        lpFilename = ""
        'get process file path
        _intLen = GetModuleFileNameEx(10000, 0, lpFilename, nSize)
    End Sub
End Class
```

But I keep getting an entrypointnotfound exception:
[image]

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok found the solution:

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Declare Function GetModuleFileNameExW Lib "PSAPI.DLL" (ByVal hProcess As Integer, ByVal hModule As Integer, ByRef lpFilename As String, ByVal nSize As Integer) As Integer
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim _intLen As Integer
        Dim lpFilename As String
        Dim nSize As Integer
        lpFilename = ""
        'get process file path
        _intLen = GetModuleFileNameExW(10000, 0, lpFilename, nSize)
    End Sub
End Class
```